# UIImagePickerController Layout Issue - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerviewcontroller

I am using UIPickerViewController to capture photo, but I am getting layout as below:

[image]

As you can see in image - The Switch camera button is not showing properly.

Below is my code

```
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = type;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong, Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: There's no need for this line imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext; When you remove this, has the issue gone?

Comment: nope, the issue still persists @JimTierney

Comment: @AngelVasa you might set the frame of imagePickercontroller , That is self.imagePickerController.frame = self.view.frame where is view is the view you want the image picker to fill [not tested]

Comment: imagePickerController.frame is not available :( @iShaalan

Comment: @AngelVasa I am sorry self. imagePickerController.view.frame

Comment: setting the frame also shows the full screen and with layout issue, actually after searching something I found 

"Apple recommends that you present the camera interface only full-screen" 

May be that is the reason why, setting the frame is not working for UIImagePickerViewController

@iShaalan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many thing, I come to know that the issue is regarding Pixate Framework.

[Pixate Issue](https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-ios/issues/169)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where in iOS 7 my status bar was not being hidden. So here's what you need to do: First set `view controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO`, then add this code before presenting view controller:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Then just add 2 delegate methods:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: sorry but issue is not about hiding and showing status bar, 

The actual thing is the switch camera button is going outside of screen offset. (as you can see in image) 

and Thanks for your answer :) @NikitaZarnov